# What makes a certain fixture burn through bulbs?

Tags: lighting

I have one outdoor fixture that inn which the bulbs burn within two or three months of being installed. This happens with both cfl and incandescent bulbs. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Insufficient cooling.

Comment: I have observed this phenomenon before, at a previous house. I never got to the bottom of it. Cooling did not seem to be the explanation. I did not measure lifetime carefully, so it may be that it was only my perception that the bulbs burned out much more frequently.

Comment: The old bulbs are usually designed for 1000 hours. As 30 days are 720 hours, the designed life time is reached after 1.5 months in 24/7 operation. However, CFLs should last 8000h, but they may suffer from humidity and low ambient temperature. Switching on/off reduces lifetime too. May be, you can tell more about the operating conditions?

Comment: each time your neighbour needs a new bulb, he takes the one outside your house

Comment: @Pete lol but in reality i only keep that light on for my nervous ninny neighbor who tells me she Grey's nervous when it's too dark and can't sleep well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metal tab in the base of the outlet has been pushed down too far (usually by overtightenig a bulb), and no longer makes good contact with the bulb. This causes sparking that gets worse as it gradually burns away the solder blob, and increases wear on the bulb.

You can tell this is happening be examining the base of the failed bulb; there will be a large divot in it.

To fix it, just pull/pry the tab up a bit. Be careful not to to electrocute yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the base of the bulb. It didn't have a divot, but it did have some corrosion. I pulled the tab out. Didn't electrocute myself:) And I guess it'll take a couple of months to see if this is the correct answer. Thanks again.